# Python Manager Dictionary Efficiency

Tags: python, dictionary, pandas, multiprocessing

I have an object oriented Python program where I am doing certain data operations in each object using multiprocessing. I am storing each object in a common manager dictionary. When I want to update an object, first, I am retrieving the object from the dictionary and after the update I am putting it back. My Class structure is like

```
from src.data_element import Data_element
from multiprocessing import freeze_support, Process, Manager
import pandas as pd

class Data_Obj(Data_element):

    def __init__(self, dataset_name,name_wo_fields, fields):
        Data_element.__init__(self, dataset_name, name_wo_fields, fields)
        self.depends=['data_1','data_2'] 

    def calc(self,obj_dict_manager):
        data_1=obj_dict_manager['data_1']
        data_2=obj_dict_manager['data_2']

        self.df = pd.merge(
                          data_1.df, 
                          data_2.df, 
                             on='week', 
                             suffixes=('', '_y')
                           )[['week','val']]


def calculate(obj_dict_manager,data): 
     data_obj=obj_dict_manager[data]    
     data_obj.calc(obj_dict_manager)
     obj_dict_manager[data]=data_obj



if __name__ == '__main__':
    freeze_support()
    manager=Manager()
    obj_dict_manager=manager.dict() 
    obj_dict_manager=create_empty_objects(obj_dict_manager)

    joblist=[]
    for data in obj_dict_manager.keys():
        p=Process(target=calculate, args=(obj_dict_manager,data))
        joblist.append(p)
        p.start()
    for job in joblist:
        job.join()
```

During these operations, there is a significant time spend on

```
data_1=obj_dict_manager['data_1']
data_2=obj_dict_manager['data_2']
```

i.e., the 1 second spend during retrieving the objects from the manager dictionary and the rest of the calculation takes another 1 second.

Is there any way that I can reduce the time spent here? I will be doing thousands of such operations and performance is critical for me.

Answer (score 0):

### An Important Note

You're doing something that is potentially dangerous: as you're iterating over the keys in obj_dict_manager, you're launching processes that modify the very same dictionary. You should never be modifying something that while you're iterating over it, and doing the modifications asynchronously from a subprocess could introduce especially strange results.

### Possible Causes of your Issue

1) I can't tell how many objects are actually stored in your shared dictionary (because we don't have the code for create_empty_objects()), but if it is a significant amount, your subprocesses may be competing for access to the shared dictionary. In particular, since you have both reading *and* writing to the dictionary, it's going to be locked by one process or another a lot of the time.

2) Since we can't see how many keys are in your shared dictionary, we also can't see how many processes are being launched. If you're creating more processes than cores on your system, you may be subjecting your CPU to a lot of [context switching](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Context_switch), which is going to slow *everything* down.

3) A combination of #1 & #2 - This could be especially problematic if the manager grants a lock to one process, then that process gets put to sleep because you have dozens of processes competing for CPU time on an 8-core machine, and now everyone has to wait until that process wakes up and releases the lock.

### How to Fix It

1) If your issue is skewed towards #1, consider splitting up your dictionary instead of utilize a shared one, and pass a chunk of the dictionary to each subprocess, let them do whatever they need, have them return the resulting dictionary, then recombine all the returned dictionaries as the processes complete. Something like [multiprocessing.map_async()](https://docs.python.org/2/library/multiprocessing.html#multiprocessing.pool.multiprocessing.Pool.map_async) may work better for you if you can divide the dictionary up.

2) In most cases, try to limit the number of processes you spawn to the number of cores you have on your system, some times even less if you have a lot of other stuff running at the same time on your system. An exception to this is if you're doing a lot of parallel processing AND you expect the subprocesses to get block a lot, like when doing IO in parallel.